# Ball that fades away as it goes to the right

Tags: java, javafx, opacity

My task is to write a program that makes a circle ball that gradually fades away as the ball moves to the right. But it's not working, I can make the ball move when the mouse is dragged but the opacity is the same. Can you guys help me? I don't know how to convert the opacity value into double

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Project3 extends Application
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      Pane root = createRootPane();
      Scene scene1 = new Scene(root);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
      primaryStage.setTitle(" Hai Vo ");
      primaryStage.show();
   }
   public Pane createRootPane()
   {
      Circle ball = new Circle (100,50,25);
      Pane root = new Pane(ball);
      root.setMinSize(300,300); 
      root.setOnMouseDragged (
       event ->
       {
         double x = event.getX();
         ball.setCenterX(event.getX());
         ball.setCenterY(event.getY());
         ball.opacityProperty().bind(ball.centerXProperty());
         double opacity = ball.opacityProperty();
         ball.setOpacity(opacity);
       } );
       return root;   
   }
}
```

Comment: In this line `duble opacity = ball.opacityProperty();`, I think you just need to fix the spelling and maybe typecast it: `double opacity = (double) ball.opacityProperty();`

Comment: oh yeah, I fixed it, but the error about converting is still the same.

Comment: The last 2 lines of the event handler don't make any sense, with or without typos. You bound the property so you cannot assign a value directly until you unbind the property. Most likely you'll get a fully opaque circle since the range of the opacity is `[0,1]` and also movement to the right increases the x value and thus the opacity evne after scaling the value depending on the maximum x value...

Comment: okay, sorry, I'm a slow learner, so you're saying that I should not bound opacity with x-value because opacity is within [0,1], while x-value can go to infinity? Then how should you suggest to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

First, move the binding out of the event handler. The binding will ensure the opacity is always updated when the `centerX` property updates.

Second, don't set bound values; the last two lines of the event handler just set the opacity to its current value anyway.

Third, the opacity should be between 0 and 1. You want it to be 1 when `centerX` is 0 and 0 when `centerX` is 300 (or, generally, the width of the pane).

What you need is (in pseudocode)

```
opacity = 1 - ball.centerX / root.width
        = (ball.centerX / root.width) * (-1) + 1
```

which you can express in bindings with

```
ball.centerXProperty()
    .divide(root.widthProperty())
    .multiply(-1)
    .add(1)
```

So put together, you need:

```
public Pane createRootPane() {
   Circle ball = new Circle (100,50,25);
   Pane root = new Pane(ball);
   ball.opacityProperty().bind(
       ball.centerXProperty()
           .divide(root.widthProperty())
           .multiply(-1)
           .add(1)
   );
   root.setMinSize(300,300); 
   root.setOnMouseDragged (
    event ->
    {
      ball.setCenterX(event.getX());
      ball.setCenterY(event.getY());
    } );
    return root;   
 }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, would you mind explaining to me the line "ball.opacityProperty......" like what is it doing specifically? What values is it playing with? 

I'm sorry, I'm new to coding, so basically, just a noob.